# Shopify order webhooks - delay before coming through

Tags: shopify

I have built an app that displays downloadable media on the checkout
completion page when someone has finished their purchase. This was based on
a webhook sending the order details to my server as soon as the purchase was
complete. This has been fine up until now but recently it has been taking
around 50 seconds after the purchase for the webhook to happen, is this a
permanent thing now?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us some code.

Comment: did you end up working around this shopify limitation mattyg? Im having a similar problem, and this minute delay is unacceptable...

Answer (score 2):

Yes. See the announcement [here](http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/announce-webhooks-don%E2%80%99t-depend-on-their-real-timey-ness-115431).